# MassTransit Send only

Tags: msmq, masstransit

I am implementing a Service Bus and having a look at MassTransit. My pattern is not Publish/Subscribe but Sender/Receiver where the Receiver can be offline and came back online later.
Right now I am starting to write my tests to verify that MassTransit succesfully deliver the message using the following code:

```
bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
{
    sbc.UseMsmq(
        cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Configurator.UseJsonSerializer();
            cfg.Configurator.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/my_queue");
            cfg.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
        });
});
```

Then I grab the bus and publish a message like this:

```
bus.Publish<TMessage>(message);
```

As I can notice from MSMQ, two queues are created and the message is sent cause Mass Transit does not raise any error but I cannot find any message in the queue container.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
Reading the Mass Transit newsgroup I found out that in a scenario of Sender/Receiver where the receiver can come online at any time later, the message can be **Send** using this code:

```
bus.GetEndpoint(new Uri("msmq://localhost/my_queue")).Send<TMessage>(message);
```

Again in my scenario I am **not writing** a Publisher/Subscriber but a Sender/Receiver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, to send, you can use a simple EndpointCacheFactory instead of a ServiceBusFactory...

```
var cache = EndpointCacheFactory.New(x => x.UseMsmq());
```

From the cache, you can retrieve an endpoint by address:

```
var endpoint = cache.GetEndpoint("msmq://localhost/queue_name");
```

Then, you can use the endpoint to send a message:

```
endpoint.Send(new MyMessage());
```

To receive, you would create a bus instance as you specified above:

```
var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(x =>
{
    x.UseMsmq();
    x.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/queue_name");

    x.Subscribe(s => s.Handler<MyMessage>(x => {});
});
```

Once your receiver process is complete, call `Dispose` on the IServiceBus instance. Once your publisher is shutting down, call `Dispose` on the IEndpointCache instance.

Do not dispose of the individual endpoints (`IEndpoint`) instances, the cache keeps them available for later use until it is disposed.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much
Documentation does not refer to the pattern Sender/Receiver unfortunately but I am glad it can be accomplished

Comment: This no longer exists. See http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/gotchas.html#send-only-bus They advise always starting and stopping the bus.

Comment: Yes this was early in the history of MassTransit.